# Select html tag text cut in half

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I been having this issue for a while..

The text of my  is always cut in half when seen from smartphone or ubuntu browser(chromium,mozilla).

[image: smartphone]

Nevertheless, when i see it on windows browsers(chrome,mozilla,explorer), looks perfectly normal.

[image: desktop]

Im using bootstrap 3.3.4

Heres some code of the select

```
<div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 0">
                                            <select name="sistema0" id="sistema0"  class="form-control" style="width: 100%; border-radius: 10px; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 15px" >
                                                <option>Elige un sistema de siembra</option>
                                                <option value="triangulo">Triángulo</option>
                                                <option value="surcos">Surcos</option>
                                                <option value="cuadro">Cuadro</option>
                                                <option value="barrera">Barrera</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>


.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}
```

[image: extraimage].

Comment: Add CSS, please. HTML is okay, problem is in CSS.

Comment: @panther There you go, i added code from bootstrap class .form-control used in inputs (also on select tag)

Answer (score 3):

As the above answer, line-height and padding might be a culprit, try to decrease your padding.

```
.form-control {
     ...
     padding: 0px 12px !important; /* until desired*/
     ...
}
```

then clear the cache. Also right clicking the element and click inspect element. Then see check the css,

Comment: This solved the issue for me(I mean editing the padding). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your CSS you are changing the line-height property on your page. Simply change the line-height on your select field and it should fix it.

**edit**

```
.form-control {
    ...
    line-height: 1 !important;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @mascaliente , that seemed to work on the other inputs but not in the select tag, i added some other bootstrap code and image if that could help.
Thanks!

Comment: @AndrésCamiloPeláez what happens if you add !important to the line-height part of your code. It looks like something is still messing with your select fields line-height. See my edit above

Comment: Almost worked for me. Instead of "line-height: 1 !important;" , I had to do "height: auto;"